# Using synonym token filters on a not tokenized field

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, token, analyzer

Let's say I want to make an autocomplete using the edge-ngram technique (the completion suggester is not a good option for me). I want to index "us army" by ["u", "us", "us ", "us a", "us ar", "us arm", "us army"].

The problem is - I also have a list of synonyms. "us", for example, is a synonym of "usa". How can I split "us army" into "us" and "army", find their synonyms and put them back together?

I tried doing something like this:

```
{
    "analysis": {
        "filter": {
            "ngram_prefix": {
                "type":     "edge_ngram",
                "min_gram": 1,
                "max_gram": 20
            },
            "custom_synonyms": {
                "type": "synonym",
                "tokenizer": "standard",
                "synonyms_path": "/my/synonym/path/synonyms.txt",
                "ignore_case": True
            }
        },
        "analyzer": {
            "synonym_ngram": {
                "type":      "custom",
                "tokenizer": "keyword",
                "filter": [
                    "custom_synonyms",
                    "lowercase",
                    "ngram_prefix",
                ],
                "char_filter": [],
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Without any luck.

Is there a way to concatenate tokens? That way I could split an entry into tokens, find the synonyms and concatenate the tokens back together?

Maybe a way to match_phrase and make sure that the first token is position 0?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that just because you have a `keyword` tokenizer. This one wouldn't split the text so that the synonyms to be identified on a per-term basis. Because of the `keyword` your `term` is the whole text. So, unless you define your synonyms like `"us army,usa army,u s a army,united states of america army"` I don't see other way:

```
 "my_synonym_filter": {
      "tokenizer": "keyword",
      "type": "synonym",
      "synonyms": [
        "us army,usa army,u s a army,united states of america army"
      ]
    }
  }
```